# Why does my ModelState.IsValid propery in my MVC application is equal to false when everything looks fine to me

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

I probably did mistake somewhere because `ModelState.IsValid` propery is allways equal to false when I'm calling my `[HttpPost]` `ActionResult`.

Here is my [HttpPost] method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditArticle(ArticleEditViewModel model)
{
   //This ModelState.IsValid is allways false
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Write something to database 
   }
}
```

Here is same but [HttpGet] Method:

```
public ActionResult EditArticle(Guid Id)
{
    Article article = Controllers.ArticleController.GetById(Id);



            if (article != null)
            {
               ArticleEditViewModel model = new ArticleEditViewModel()
                {
                    articleID = article.articleID,
                    ValidFrom = article.ValidFrom,
                    ValidTo = (DateTime)article.ValidTo,
                    Code = article.Code,
                };

                return View(model);
            }
            return View("NotFound");

        }
```

Here is how my form looks (as you can see Code is not null and Valid to and valid from also has some value):

[image]

But in my visual studio when I'm debugging I'm getting next values:

[image]

I can not understand how come this Propertys are null and with some strange values as "1.1.0001" for `ValidFrom` when they are shown on view are they have some values in text boxes.

And final, here is my view:

```
@model MyProject.Web.Models.BaseData.ArticleEditViewModel


@using MyProject.DataAccess.Model
@using MyProject.Web.Helpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit articles";
}

<div class="">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditArticle", "Articles", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", id = "demo-form2" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ArticleID)

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
                                <span class="fa fa-barcode form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </div>

                            //Some other divs which and textboxes which are not important for us right now

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidFrom)

                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValidFrom, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidFrom)

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidTo)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValidTo, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidTo)

                            </div>
                        </div>

</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: If the fields are disabled their values won't be posted. Consider using a different UI.

Comment: @KarelTamayo can you recommend me something?

Comment: Lets have a look at the ArticleEditViewModel

Comment: Yeap. You could for instance render readonly values as labels instead of textboxes and render hidden fields for the actual values if they can't be calculated on the controller. Or render labels so the user can see but calculate the values on the controller.

Comment: @KarelTamayo  You could post this as answer I will accept it, because after I added this : @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AppropiatePropery ) I get values on my PostBack, and interesting thing is that I'm getting current datetime for values ValidTo and ValidFrom even if that is not their real value, but whatever it's better than null or 1.1.0001...

Comment: @RoxyPro got it! Will post an answer ASAP. The interesting part you say is called ModelBinding. Do you initialize your DateTime fields in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fields are rendered disabled they won't be posted.

You have a couple of options here:

> Render readonly fields as labels

If you can't calculate the values for the readonly fields you can use hidden fields to post the values:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DateTo)
```

> Render disabled inputs

If you know you can calculate the values in the controller you can then 
render the fields as you're doing now but in the action before the condition, calculate the values you know are not posting.

```
public IActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    // Calculate the values here
    If (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you shortly please explain to me what is the meaning of @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DateTo) in my View and how come after that line that my DateTo has some sense value ( current datetime ) in my Controller.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Sorry I did miss your last comment. I'll get back to you ASAP. I'm at the office now.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro here you go: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sV30W5. `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DateTo)` will render a hidden field in your form that will hold the value of the property `DateTo`. Let me know if it helps.